# How to display positive and negative values in positive side of graph in Highchart?

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

If I try to display highchart with positive and negative number in colum highchart, the negative values print in negative axis of the chart. But I want to display the positive and negative values in same side (positive side) of the chart with proper total value in top.
Help me to solve the problem.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want to display.  Should column 1 show the -31 and -5 as positive values?

Comment: Assuming you want them side-by-side - add them as two different data sets, with the -ve ones added as +v1.  No idea about the total though.  Not sure how else you want them displayed, unless you want to [abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) them.

Comment: Thanks for yours reply.
I want to display both the positive and negative values in same columns. In above case, you van see, in a first bar, 3 is displayed in a positive side. but -31 and -5 is displayed in negative side of chart (Here I mean negative is -10,-20,-30 of chart Y axis.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will achieve it using series.column.threshold setting your value to the Y axis as the base for the columns.

On the example, I change threshold and all the negative values are under the 5.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: "normal",
        threshold: 5
    }
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w63yeg9d/

API References: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.threshold